# Migration of large database from mysql to postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In my system I want to migrate my full database from mysql to postgresql

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+--------------+
| VERSION()    |
+--------------+
| 5.1.73-1-log |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)


shell=# SELECT version();
                                           version                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Is it possible to convert my full database using any migration tools or using any php or perl script?

In mysql I have three views also which I also want to convert into postgresql tabes using this migration also.

Comment: If this were my problem, I would be the tool.

Comment: i had made full script for it for migration but its not work fine each time even in that i made put all debug points but its not work fine for millions of records after some millions of records its stop working automatically without leave any debug points so i am not able to trace my script so i thought that kind of solution for it

Comment: I would do it manually.

Comment: yeah that is good idea but when we have millions of records so that time how we can know about error point today i got in mysql table 1,37,00,000 records and after 22,00,000 its stop working automatically so i cant get any idea why this happened ? i have made block of 1000 records and do it same as it

Comment: Usually the easiest way: create the approriate DDL script to setup the tables in Postgres (can be done with some intelligent search & replace from the MySQL scripts you have). The export the data as CSV files and import them into Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can look **pentaho Spoon Data Integration**. its free tool and i saw using this tool for migration db2 to sqlserver. Maybe you can use pantaho

download link:

http://community.pentaho.com/projects/data-integration/

here is documentation of spoon:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Latest+Pentaho+Data+Integration+%28aka+Kettle%29+Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Try [FromMySqlToPostgreSql](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/FromMySqlToPostgreSql).
This tool is feature-reach and easy to use. It maps data-types, migrates constraints, indexes, PKs and FKs exactly as they were in your MySQL db. Under the hood it uses PostgreSQL COPY, so data transfer is very fast.
It also has a basic views migration support.
View definitions (SQL), of views, that were not migrated can be found under

```
/FromMySqlToPostgreSql/logs_directory/not_created_views
```

.
These view definitions (SQL) can be a little bit rewritten in order to match PostgreSQL syntax (for example use of COALESCE() instead of IFNULL()).